# How do create the side-drawer controller?

Tags: cosmicmind

I am fairly new to iOS. I have been able to successfully implement the the material buttons and card view but how the side-drawer controller is done on storyboard isn't making sense to me. Can you anyone help with sample code on storyboard?

Looking for a simple View Controller with a navigation button that opens the sidedrawercontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, if you want to use `NavigationDrawerController`, you have to initialize the `NavigationDrawerController` programmatically.

However, you still can layout your root view controller and side controller by storyboard, and make sure you give them proper Storyboard ID in the Interface Builder.

Here is my code in **AppDelegate.swift**

```
let mainViewController         = instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! MainViewController        
let sideMenuViewController     = instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SideMenuViewController") as! SideMenuViewController
let navigationController       = NavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController, leftViewController: sideMenuViewController)        
let navigationDrawerController = NavigationDrawerController(rootViewController: navigationController)

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window?.rootViewController = navigationDrawerController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

P.S. If you want to use UINavigationController, just embed the "MainViewController" with UINavigationViewController in storyboard, and give **the UINavigationViewController** a Storyboard ID. At last, set the `rootViewController` to your `UINavigationController` instance, instead of the `MainViewController`.

**Updated** with **`Swift3`** and **`Material 2.0`**

```
func instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UIViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
}

let mainViewController = instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
let sideMenuViewController = instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier: "SideMenuViewController") as! SideMenuViewController
let navigationController = NavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
let navigationDrawerViewController = NavigationDrawerController(rootViewController: navigationController, leftViewController: sideMenuViewController, rightViewController: nil)

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.rootViewController = navigationDrawerViewController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: hey do you have a swift 3 version of this problem. After I run a login check, I want to switch to the mainViewController. I want to add the sideMenuViewController capability to the mainViewController. How does the code change here? because with this code, It loads the mainViewController initially at launch. If you help me, Ill give you the accepted answer ;)

Comment: If you want to load your loginViewController before presenting your mainViewController, you can use native `present:viewControllerToPresent:animated:completion` function to present the `navigationDrawerViewController ` generated by the above code. Or if you just want to do some login check without any user interface, then you can use above code to change your `window's rootViewController` after finishing the login check.